# Unable to install lxc or lxc-utils in Bionic Beaver Server 18.04

Tags: lxc

I have a basic up to date install of 18.04 server. Only the universe repository has been added above the default installation. No third party repos.

When I try to install package lxc I get the following error:

```
lxc : Depends: lxc-utils (>= 3.0.0-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
```

So I try to install lxc-utils. But it also has broken dependencies:

```
lxc-utils : Depends: liblxc1 (= 3.0.0-0ubuntu2) but 3.0.1-0ubuntu1~18.04.2 is to be installed
```

Is this intentional, should I now be using something else for LXC capability?

Comment: Does `sudo apt install -f` help?

Comment: This kind of version mismatch should be fixed by a normal `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` before trying to install lxc.

Comment: System is fully up to date, both packages and repos. Am suspecting there's actually broken dependencies in the Bionic repos.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was `/etc/apt/sources.list`

I thought that `universe` should be added separately to the default three lines

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic universe
```

This is not right. It should look like this

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main universe
```

There is a bug report against Bionic server installs missing `universe`
https://bugs.launchpad.net/subiquity/+bug/1783129